# Replace the wrapper (parent) string by regular expression and preserve the inner child content

Tags: php, regex

I have multiple files which have obsolete format and I would like to replace them with the latest format. One of my trouble is finding all the wrapper string and replace them all while I have to preserve their inner content.

**Example**

I want to convert an expression `ABC($IGNORE$)` to `XBD([$IGNORE$])->T`.
Here is the string the format of which needs updating.

*Input*:

```
... ABC( ......
..... (inner content should not be changed) .....
......) ....
```

*Output*:

```
... XBD([ ......
..... (inner content should not be changed) .....
......])->T ....
```

How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex that is able to match nested round brackets:

```
\bABC(\(((?>[^()]+)|(?-2))*\))
```

Replace with `XBD$1->T`.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zP3gV8/1)

[Sample PHP code](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMRHJha2g4dnhCczA):

```
<?php
    $re = "#\bABC(\(((?>[^()]+)|(?-2))*\))#"; 
    $str = "ABC( ......\n..... (inner content should not be changed) .....\n......) "; 
    $subst = "XBD$1->T"; 
    echo $result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
?>
```